# How can I sort a range in VBA without hard-coding the first cell of the sorted column?

Tags: excel, vba, csv

Our company database generates a CSV list of a given client's expenses and payments, and I am trying to create a Macro that will use the CSV to create invoices for our clients.

The CSV is formatted so that the list of payments appears a few rows below the list of expenses, both of which may vary in length.  The columns in each section also represent different things (e.g. column B starts off showing the client surname in the expense section, and payment date down in the payment section).  Because of this, the macro must not hard-code the start and end positions of each range when operating on them (which it does when I simply record it).

One portion of code is designed to sort the payments by date:

```
Dim PaymentsTable As Range
Set PaymentTable = ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow, 1).CurrentRegion

Dim PaymentDate As Range
Set PaymentDate = PaymentTable.Columns(2)

PaymentDate.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

PaymentTable.Sort Key1:=Range("PaymentDate"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```

The program can correctly identify column 2, as texted in the penultimate line (which colours it red).  However, the final line always generates the following error:

> "Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed."

I can remove this error by giving an absolute cell location in Key1 (e.g. "A1").

Why am I getting this error?  How can I alter my code to remove it?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give the range `PaymentTable` directly as you already definde it as `Dim PaymentDate As Range`.

```
PaymentTable.Sort Key1:=PaymentTable, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```

If you use `Range("PaymentDate")` it looks for a named range `"PaymentDate"` which is not the variable `PaymentDate`.

Comment: Thank you very much!  It worked perfectly.